# What is a suitable Chinese name for a fictional company called "The Unity Group"?

Tags: translation, word-choice

I'm currently writing a novel featuring Chinese characters, with one being among the protagonists.

Some of them are employees of a corporation, and I simply don't trust Google translate enough.  The name of the company is **"The Unity Group"**.  Not the *Unity Corporation*, but specifically *Group*.

Google translate says it is *Tuanjie Tuanti*, is that correct?  I tried it in various alternatives which confused the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would say that depends on the nuances in The Unity Group.

"Some of them are employees of a Corporation"

Assume Group means 'Group of Companies，corporate group', a kind of financial wizardry for holding more than one company as separate tax entities.

corporate group: 公司 集团 gōngsī jítuán

Unity? Maybe: 团结 tuánjié

团结 就是 力量 tuánjié jiùshì lìliáng = Unity is strength

But maybe you mean unity as 'the only, we brook no challengers'? Like here:

德国 统一 社会 党 déguó tǒngyī shèhuì dǎng Sozialistische Einheitspartei Deutschlands  (Socialist Unity Party of Germany 1949-1990)

Here, unity is 统一 tǒngyī This means 'united' but actually they meant: the only party

(I've split the words for your clarity. Normally, everything is written together.)

Choose one: 统一 公司 团结 tǒngyī gōngsī tuánjié or 团结 公司 集团 tuánjié gōngsī jítuán

团体 also means 'organized group, team, organization'

Then there is 单位 work unit and 组织 organize, organization

Maybe you better clarify how you mean 'The Unity Group'.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Pedroski. If i have to choose one, id have to go with The Unity Group as in a corporation of companies.

Answer (score 1):

Translation of commercial brands is not only about finding a phrase having the same meanings~ e.g. 联合利华 for Unilever: While 联合 is directly from uni-, 利华 is a clever transliteration of -lever, which gives the impression of "benefiting China". In fact, many still assume it is a Chinese company!

I would say Pedroski gives accurate translation, but it's no good for a company name.

I propose 优联体集团. But now I have to handle some other bussiness, so I will further explain it later.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who is a practicing company man for the past 4 decades, perhaps I can chip in.

1. when you are incorporating a company as a single corporate entity, you say "ABC 公司", (without going into details about limited and unlimited liability matters)

Of course if you wish to be specific as to the company's core business, you can add:-

---   ABC 贸易 公司, "ABC Trading Co", or,

---   ABC 建筑 公司, "ABC Construction Co."

2. when you are incorporating a "Group" of companies, or a company is part of a conglomerate, (i.e. a group of diverse companies under common ownership and run as a single organization), then the common practice is to use 集团 or 集團, for example the "Kaifu Energy Group Co., Ltd. (凱富能源*集團*有限公司), which is listed on the HK Stock Exchange. (please, I have no shares in this Group, :) )

In your case, leaving aside the "Group" nomenclature issue, you do have a wide choice as to naming, in Chinese, the "Unity" part.

This, in a way, depends on the story line; is it corporate intrigue, commercial espionage, office romance, money-laundering, etc,? You may wish to choose the particular "unity" to reflect that.

Someone suggested 优联, (Yōu lián) This term is commonly used to mean in English "Union", (like the "Union Omnibus Co.), which by sheer coincidence not only has the same meaning but nicely transliterated as well.